# Database error on installing Wordpress on Webmatrix

Tags: mysql, wordpress, webmatrix-2

I am completely new to CMS and Word Press, though I have heard of it a lot. I recently downloaded and installed Webmatrix2 and there, in the App Gallery, I clicked Wordpress to install Wordpress. It asked for a name and then checked if I have Mysql installed, I had. Then I enetered the password for **root**, and it gave me this following error:
[image: Error]

I am entering the only password that I used while setting up MySQL. I also tried installing Joomla, with MS SQL Server and MYSQL Server, same error! Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem once, but I just uninstalled the MySQL and WebMatrix and then installed WebMatrix and went into the app gallery and installed Wordpress (and automatically SQL) I was asked to give it a new password and problem solved

Comment: I installed MySQL explicitly, may be that is the problem! Currently, I open Wordpress folder as site in WebMatrix. It works fine.